# Can you create input actions using more than one key in the editor with the new Input System?

Tags: unity

The new input system documentation says it's possible to add actions that require input combinations within the editor or code. I only see an option to add one binding path per action within in the Actions UI.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/blob/develop/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem/Documentation~/HowDoI.md#-require-the-left-trigger-to-be-held-and-then-the-a-button-to-be-pressed-and-held-for-04-seconds):

> ... require the left trigger to be held and then the A button to be pressed and held for 0.4 seconds?
>
> ```
> var action = new InputAction();
> action.AddBinding("/<gamepad>/leftTrigger")
>     .CombinedWith("/<gamepad>/buttonSouth", modifiers: "hold(duration=0.4)");
> ```
>
> Again, setting this up with the inspector in the editor is an alternative to dealing with the path strings directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple simple (i.e. one key/button) bindings per single InputAction is currently possible. Complex (multiple keys per single) binding was possible too but at some point there was a major rework of the new InputSystem. And to my best knowledge after the rework that feature no longer exists (as of today, ver 0.2.0). The guys working on the InputSystem said they plan to add it again.

P.S. There is customization available through Interactions but its relatively limited (as of ver 0.2.0) And i read that they will be doing additional pass to refine them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the most recent [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/blob/develop/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem/Documentation%7E/ActionBindings.md#one-modifier), it is possible to configure one or two modifiers.
With some luck, I can try it today..